# Check whether a set is well-defined or not

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is probably a very basic question: how do we check whether a set is well-defined or not?

For example, $X$ is a set. Let $\tau = \{U\subset X|$ $U^c$ is finite or is $X\}$, $\tau$ is a topology on $X$. My way of checking that it is well-defined is: take a specific $U\subset X$, the set will tell me whether it's in the set or not, so it is well-defined. Is it a good way to check?

Another example is: Suppose that $U$ is a subset of an inner product space $V$, $U^{\perp} = \{v: \langle u,v\rangle = 0$ for all $u\in U \}$ is called the *orthogonal complement* of $U$. How do we check that $U^{\perp}$ is well-defined (exists and is unique)?

At some point, I was suddenly unsure about sets whose elements can not be listed/don't have a pattern. Is it that if take a specific element, we can tell whether it's in the set or not, then the set is well-defined? But I feel like I fail to see the essence of some sets in this way..

Comment: For first example, if $U\subset X$ and $U^c=X\setminus U$, then $X\setminus U = X$ is equivalent $U=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it that if take a specific element, we can tell whether it's in
> the set or not, then the set is well-defined?

This is a helpful mental model, but "we can tell" should perhaps be replaced by God can tell. That is, as long as the rules are clear, even if we don't know the answer to the question, the set is still well-defined. Take for example the set $P$ of all well-formed programs, and $H$ the subset that eventually halts. Even though the halting problem cannot be solved, that is we don't know how to determine if a given program will halt or not, we still know $H$ is well-defined. There is no ambiguity for whether a program will halt or not, whether the Riemann's hypothesis is true or not, even though we currently don't know the answer to these questions. This is different from say the set of old people: how old is old? There is ambiguity.

In theory, a set can be formed only through a few specific rules made clear in e.g. the [ZFC axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). In particular, you can form the union, intersection and power sets, etc.

In practice, the most important thing is the [Axiom of Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification), that is any well-defined proposition (with no ambiguity) can be used to cut a set out of a pre-existing bigger set (which is needed to resolve Russell's paradox), that is the set $\{x\in S \mid p(x) \}$ exists (as long as $S$ is a set and $p(x)$ is a well-formed proposition).

In the case of $\tau$, it was cut out of the power set of $X$, hence well-defined. As for $U^{\perp}$, the proposition is used to cut those $v$ out of the bigger $V$ (but whether $U^{\perp}$ is a subspace needs a proof).

As for the uniqueness, it basically follows from the axiom of extensionality. Roughly, an element $x$ either satisfies the property $p(x)$ or not, and $\{x\in S \mid p(x)\}$ contains precisely those $x$ from $S$ that make $p(x)$ true.

As uncountable sets are everywhere, there is no hope to list elements of an arbitrary set. In a certain sense, $p(x)$ is the pattern for $\{x\in S\mid p(x)\}$.

However, you have to be careful when a single element could have different presentations that might cause ambiguity. For example $X=\{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb Q\mid a\in\mathbb Z, b\in\mathbb 2\mathbb Z\}$ is a well-defined set, and if we ask if $\frac{2}{3}$ is in $X$, the answer is surprisingly yes! That's because by definition, $X$ consists all of the fractions whose denominators are even, and $\frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{6}\in X$. From here, it's easy to see $X=\mathbb Q$.

This is in general not a problem for forming a set, but often an obstacle for defining a function, e.g. $f:\mathbb Q\rightarrow\mathbb Z$ defined by $f(\frac{a}{b})=a+b$ is not well-defined, because the same number $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$ was mapped to distinct images by the rule: $f(1/2)=1+2=3, f(2/4)=2+4=6$.

Comment: +1 for _God can tell_.

Comment: @Just a user Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I just read the axioms, just to make sure, is it that Axiom of Specification alone can't guarantee the uniqueness of these sets? The Axiom of Specification is very useful, but also curious: if given a set, God can tell whether a random element is in the set following the description of the set, does it mean that the set is well-defined?

Comment: @Coco Yeah, Axiom of Specification only guarantees the existence and then the Axiom of Extensionality guarantees the uniqueness. For the second problem, as long as the set is not too big. That is if we have a proposition/God to filer elements, we essentially have a "class", and it is not necessarily a set, due to Russell's paradox:  the proposition could be "is a set", then we are in trouble, as there is no set of all sets.

Comment: @Justauser Thank you! I have another question. When you said $p(x)$ is a well-formed proposition in the third paragraph, do you mean that given a $x\in S$, $p(x)$ is either true or false?

Comment: @Coco, yes, that's pretty much it. Unless you really want to get down to the foundations of mathematics to elimiate any possible ambiguity, it is known as ["predicate" or "well-formed formula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) in first order logic, but it is unnecessary in order to study other branches of mathematics, including point-set topology. The so-called "naive set theory" suffices.

Comment: Thank you! @Justauser

Comment: Hi, sorry to ask again, but by saying "naive set theory" suffices, do you mean that  if I have a collection and God can tell whether a random object is in the collection or not (no ambiguity), then the collection is a well-defined set in naive set theory? @Justauser

Comment: "[Naive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory)" is an informal but established term to mean set theory that is different from formal or axiomatic set theory. Here I am using it pretty casually to mean set theory that reflects "common sense", that is not to worry too much about the formality, rigor or paradoxes.

Answer (score 1):

The modern axiomatic systems ZF (Zermelo-Frankel) and ZFC (ZF plus the axiom of Choice) include the Power Axiom : $\forall X\,\exists Y\,\forall Z\, (Z\in Y\iff Z\subseteq X)$, and the Axiom Schema of  Comprehension (Specification): $\forall X\,\exists Y\,\forall Z\, (Z\in Y\iff [Z\in X\land f(Z)])$, where $f(Z)$ is any property that can be stated in the formal Language Of Set Theory (LOST). It is called a schema because there is a separate axiom for each $f(Z)$ that can be stated.

These axioms imply the existence of the sets in your examples. Their uniqueness is implied by the Axiom of Extensionality (also a part of ZF): $\forall X,Y\,(X=Y\iff \forall Z\,[Z\in X\iff Z\in Y]).$

Comprehension replaced an earlier attempt $\exists Y\,\forall Z\, (Z\in Y\iff f(Z)),$ known as Abstraction, which leads to Russell's Paradox when $f(Z)$ is $Z\not\in Z$.